# Remove white space from JSON object, but not within quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, json

So I have an `input[type="text"]`, where I want to paste JSON object as configuration. Output in console is perfect, all inline without any trimming, but now in that `input` I have lots of spacing. I'd like to get rid of that spacing and replace the `input` value.

**Example**

```
$('#widget-json').on('input propertychange', function () {
    var string = this.value.replace(/\s+/g, ''),
        data = $.parseJSON( string );

    $(this).val( string );
});
```

That almost do the job, but it also removes spacing within quotes. So if I had a key/val like `"sentence": "Sure thing, good to go."`, that would get converted into `"sentence":"Surething,goodtogo."`, while I'd want to preserve spacing within quotes.

**JSON Object Example**

```
{
    "widget-effect": 3,
    "widget-opacity-color": "#C7C9CF",
    "widget-opacity-slider": "50%",
    "widget-opt-close": false,
    "widget-opt-scroll": true,
    "widget-opt-totop": true,
    "widget-text": "Spacing required within quotes"
}
```

**Desired Output Example**

```
{"widget-effect":3,"widget-opacity-color":"#C7C9CF","widget-opacity-slider":"50%","widget-opt-close":false,"widget-opt-scroll":true,"widget-opt-totop":true,"widget-text": "Spacing required within quotes"}
```

- I tried, `jQuery.trim( this.value )` and that did not work at all.
- I tried, `this.value.replace(/\s+/g, '')` and that removed entire whitespace, even within quotes. I know that it is probably correct outcome, but I have no ideas how to remove it only outside of quotes.

*I am assuming that that regex could be fitted to skip replacing spacing inside of quotes, but I'm not really familiar with it at all.*

Comment: Parse it and re-serialize it.

Comment: What was the actual desired behavior?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use regex alternation operator.

```js
var s = '"sentence": "Sure thing, good to go."';
alert(s.replace(/("[^"]*")|\s/g, "$1"))
```

**What actually the above regex do?**

- `("[^"]*")` captures all the double quoted blocks. So in the above, `"sentence"` and `"Sure thing ..."` are captured (means this particular part would be stored into a temp buffer of index 1).
- `|` OR
- `\s` matches all the space characters from the remaining string. So it won't touch the previous matched parts.
- `$1` in the replacement part refers all the chars which are captured by the first capturing group. So chars in the first capturing groups are retained and the matched spaces got removed.

**Update:**

> Unfortunately, when you escape a quote in the value of the string the regex breaks and stops removing spaces for the remaining key/value pairs

```js
var stri = `"sentence \\"with escaped quotes\\" should not break": "Sure thing, good to go."`;
alert(stri.replace(/("(?:\\"|[^"])*")|\s/g, "$1"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much Avinash. That is exactly doing what I wanted.

Comment: Hi Avinash. Unfortunately, when you escape a quote in the value of the string the regex breaks and stops removing spaces for the remaining key/value pairs. I've been trying to apply a negative lookbehind to the trailing quote in the capturing group but that provokes the whitespaces in the string to be consumed because for some reason it doesn't consider the opening quote. If you can came up with an improved version that would be great

Answer (score 3):

Try utilizing `JSON.stringify`

```
$("#widget-json").on("input propertychange", function () {
    // var string = this.value.replace(/\s+/g, ''),
    var data = JSON.stringify($.parseJSON( this.value ));
    $(this).val( data );
});
```

---

```js
var data = {
    "widget-effect": 3,
    "widget-opacity-color": "#C7C9CF",
    "widget-opacity-slider": "50%",
    "widget-opt-close": false,
    "widget-opt-scroll": true,
    "widget-opt-totop": true,
    "widget-text": "Spacing required within quotes"
};

document.write(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: I see... Quite good to know. +1
Although I will "Mark as correct" @Avinash_Raj's answer. Since I asked for possible way and wanted to know how to do it with Regex.